# Select data between December of previous year and November of current year, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve statistical data between December of the previous year and November of the current year. The `date` column of my table has the data type of `date`.

The following SQL works fine with the obvious problem that it only works if the year is manually changed. How would one accomplish the same with a dynamically changing year for this time period?

```
SELECT date, SUM(numCalls) AS callTotal FROM callstats_callData
WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2012-11-01'
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

The data is being retrieved from a MySQL table by PHP.

**UPDATE**

The code below works but I was hoping to have an SQL based solution.

```
$date1 = (date("Y") - 1) . '12-01';
$date2 = date("Y") . '-11-01';
$fetchTotals = $this->contentDB->prepare("SELECT date, SUM(numCalls) AS callTotal FROM callstats_callData
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date");
$fetchTotals->execute(array($date1, $date2));
$totals = $fetchTotals->fetchAll();
```

**Working Example**

This is to retrieve the call data for the Total Calls chart [here](http://callaovfd.org/call-stats). The results need to be retrieved in a loop in order to display the total for each month in that period of time. This page is currently working properly using the PHP & MySQL code above, just hoping for an SQL based solution.

Comment: Where is this SQL call being made from? If it's automated/generated by a PHP page or similar, you can just generate the year there; if you're typing it in by hand, you have no problem.

Comment: This is being done in PHP. I tried a prepared statement with the date range and it did not execute - `..WHERE date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2`

Comment: You should edit that information as well as the code for the stored procedure you used into the original question. Question asking 101: we can't help you with what you don't tell us about.

Comment: Sorry, i don't believe I used a stored procedure? Updated the question to mention it is being retrieved by PHP. Rather thought this was something that would be more related to the SQL statement itself

Comment: Prepared statement. Typo, sorry. In any case, *show us exactly what you did.*

Comment: See above, with a working solution that is based on PHP... not sure if I should just go with this or if there is a better way to go about it with pure SQL. I attempted this way prior to posting my question and it did not work, not sure what I did wrong initially. And the original question was not using a prepared statement, the question was how to do the same without manually inputting the between dates in the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you a bit of flexibility in selecting arbitrary month and day values for updated queries - as you set in your posted PHP code:

```
SELECT date, SUM(numCalls) AS callTotal 
FROM callstats_callData
WHERE DATE(date) 
BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1,'-12-01') AND CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-11-01')
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stored Procedure with your above query and taking arguments startDate & endDate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
SELECT 
    date, SUM(numCalls) AS callTotal 
FROM 
    callstats_callData
WHERE 
    (MONTH(date) >= 12 AND YEAR(date) = (YEAR(NOW()) - 1)) OR 
    (YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) < 11);
GROUP BY 
    date 
ORDER BY 
    date
```

---

**EDIT:** 
Seeing your comment, I suppose the best way to do it would be:

```
SELECT 
    date, SUM(numCalls) AS callTotal 
FROM 
    callstats_callData
WHERE 
    (MONTH(date) >= 12 AND YEAR(date) = (YEAR(NOW()) - 1)) OR 
    (YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) < 11);
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(date), MONTH(date) 
ORDER BY 
    date
```

Comment: This gives me the total number of calls for that period of time. I left out a crucial piece of information - see question update in a minute

Answer (score 0):

The sql function YEAR(GETDATE()) returns the current year. You can try to use it in your query.